# 802.1X authentication with NetworkManager

Tags: networking, networkmanager, 802.1x

I have a plain DHCP wired connection at home, and a wired connection secured with 802.1X at the office. I need to use the right parameters in each location.

I've configured both connections with NetworkManager, but now when I'm at home the NM GUI asks me to re-enter identity data, it doesn't try to establish an unsecured connection.

How can I configure the NetworkManager to use the right connection in both locations? Are there any attributes for wired networks, like, a MAC of the DHCP server, or the availability of the authentication server? I can also use another utility instead of NM if it's easier.

Comment: How is it supposed to figure out which is the correct one?

Comment: It's easy for it to figure out wireless since different networks have different ESSIDs. With ethernet it's just "cable plugged in".

Comment: What do you mean by “secured”? NM usually works out of the box where DHCP is available. Is there a DHCP server at your office? If not, what kind of setup is it: a static IPv4 address? Is it in a public range or [private range](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4_address#Private_networks)?

Comment: @Gilles : "Secured" means an authentication via the 802.1x protocol family - by certificate.

Comment: @jordanm : That's the part of the question - are there any attributes for wired networks? - Like, a MAC of the DHCP server, or an availability of the authentication server. For now the NM GUI only asks to re-enter identity data, if it fails to establish secured connection - it doesn't try any other connection.